# MongoDB: Редактировать запись в коллекции с удалением полей

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Добрый день Дорогие коллеги, столкнулся с проблемой, представляю Вам упрощенную версию кода. Заранее Спасибо!

---

У меня есть документ:

```
{
  _id: '11111',
  companyId: '1',
  name: 'Ilya',
  phone: '+777777777777',
}
```

Мне нужно обновить документ:

```
.findOneAndUpdate({_id: '11111'}, {name: 'Ivan'})
```

Результат должен быть:

```
{
  _id: '11111',
  companyId: '1',
  name: 'Ivan',
}
```

Свойство, которое не указано(phone), должно быть удалено при этом companyId должено остаться.

---

Логика такая, мы заменяем человека но рабочее место остается тоже самое.

id и id компании, остаются прежние. Но все что касается человека его имя и тд. приходят от нового человека соотетстенно все поля связание со старим пользователем надо удалить.

Как можно это сделать?

Comment: По какому критерию `phone` должен быть удален, а `companyId` - нет?

Comment: Спасибо за коментарий, сейчас исправлю вопрос немного. Опишу более детально принцип работи приложения.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459086/how-do-i-unset-all-fields-except-a-known-set-of-fields

Comment: Yaant  спасибо за ссилку!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте $unset - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/

`.findOneAndUpdate({_id: '11111'}, {$set:{name: "Ivan"}, $unset:{phone:""}})`

Comment: Спасибо Петр, попробую $unset